# Rails rendering an html tag from helper.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
def helper_method
   "<a href='#{movie_path(user.wants_to_see_movies.first)}'>#{user.wants_to_see_movies.first.title.titleize}</a>".html_safe
end
```

I'm trying to generate a link from above helper method but instead it's showing up as `Wants to see <a href='/movies/2'>Spectre</a>` in the view.

1. First, what am I doing wrong? I thought html_safe would solve this.
2. Is there a way to do this with a link_to instead?

Comment: Are you calling your helper method directly from the view or via another helper method?

Comment: directly from the view

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not certain as to why `html_safe` isn't working but you should be able to use `link_to` like

```
def helper_method
  movie = user.wants_to_see_movies.first
  link_to movie.title.titleize, movie
end
```